# ShareThis shares an incorrect URL

Tags: sharethis

I have incorporated the ShareWidget on the profile pages of www.hireinfluence.com

e.g.

1. https://beta.hireinfluence.com/shardulbhatt
2. https://beta.hireinfluence.com/HireInfluence

As I am using this over https, I have included the button.js available over http://ws.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js

Further, the og:url tag on the page also points to the URL seen in the browser.

Somehow the URL shared by the ShareThis widget is always info.hireinfluence.com instead of the one in the browser address bar.

Can someone please help me resolve this issue?

Thanks
Shardul.

Comment: the meta in the view source is <meta content='https://www.hireinfluence.com' property='og:url'> also the image is not the person's image

Comment: Are you using Chrome? If so a Sheild icon would appear in the address bar and you would have to click on it to let the ShareThis script execute. 

The documentation on ShareThis says that over HTTPS, we should use http://ws.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js instead of http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js and I have done that. Even that the browser blocks the script.

Comment: Ok, I see it. I have fixed it now. The issue now is that the images on the shared URL are not shared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ShareThis has a tweak where you can add: `expr:st_title='data:post.title' expr:st_url='data:post.url'` to each button, forcing the share buttons to share the link in the post instead of the link in the broswer.

The code would look something similar to this:

```
    < span class='st_twitter_hcount' expr:st_title='data:post.title' expr:st_url='data:post.url'/>
< span class='st_facebook_hcount' expr:st_title='data:post.title' expr:st_url='data:post.url'/> 
< span class='st_googleplus_hcount' expr:st_title='data:post.title' expr:st_url='data:post.url'/> 
< span class='st_linkedin_hcount' expr:st_title='data:post.title' expr:st_url='data:post.url'/>
```

That should also solve the image issue too.

Comment: I had many share buttons ( Custom share button from Sharethis ) in one page and the above solution didn't work for me, but adding the `data-short-url` solved the issue.